# Validity of applying cross-section analyses to balanced panel data

Tags: r, panel-data, difference-in-difference, matching, cross-section

(I apologize if this question is off-topic.)

I would like to apply a method developed for time-series cross-section data to a balanced panel dataset to estimate the effect of a treatment. What I mean by that is, instead of using a standard panel data model (e.g., Pooled OLS, fixed-effects, etc.), the method I would like to use "breaks" the panel data into cross-sections and analyze the data that way (i.e., through multiple cross-section comparisons). I want to believe there is no problem analyzing my balanced panel data that way, but perhaps I am missing something?

As a side note, I am using the matching method developed by [Imai et al. 2018](http://web.mit.edu/insong/www/pdf/tscs.pdf) (that actually uses a   nonparametric generalization of the difference-in-differences estimator), implemented through the '[PanelMatch](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/PanelMatch/index.html)' package for R. The authors of the package are currently working on how to implement that method to continuous treatments (which would be the ideal case for me), but again, I wonder if I could apply that method to a balanced panel data ignoring the fact that I have a continuous treatment. Thank you in advance.